# Google Calendar PHP - Event URL / ID? (Zend_Gdata)

Tags: php, events, zend-framework, calendar

I have modified my PHP web app to add events to a Google Calendar. Currently, it adds successfully.

However, now I wish to delete and edit events. This seems easy to do, except for the fact that I don't know what event URL is associated with each event.

Am I supposed to set this event URL (or ID?) upon adding an event? How am I supposed to figure out what it is?

I can't seem to find this information anywhere else...

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have been using the Zend Framework for this (Gdata package)...

EDIT:

```
$newIncludePath = array();

$newIncludePath[] = '../ZendGdata-1.8.4PL1/library';

$newIncludePath = implode($newIncludePath);

set_include_path($newIncludePath);



  // load classes

  require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';

  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');

  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');

  Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Http_Client');



  // connect to service

  $gcal = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME;

  $user = "********@gmail.com";

  $pass = "*****";

  $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user, $pass, $gcal);

  $gcal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);



  // construct event object

  // save to server      

  try {

    $event = $gcal->newEventEntry();        

    $event->title = $gcal->newTitle($title); 

    $event->content = $gcal->newContent($desc);       

    $when = $gcal->newWhen();

    $when->startTime = $date;

    $when->endTime = $date;

    $event->when = array($when);        

    $gcal->insertEvent($event);   

echo $event->getEditLink()->href;


  } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {

    echo "Error: Unable to add event to Google Calendar" . $e->getResponse();

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is plainly documented in the Zend_Gdata documentation:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.calendar.html#zend.gdata.calendar.deleting_events

```
// Option 1: Events can be deleted directly
$event->delete();
```

or

```
// Option 2: Events can be deleted supplying the edit URL of the event
// to the calendar service, if known
$service->delete($event->getEditLink()->href);
```

It sounds like you need the latter.

**Edit:**

Get the edit link from your $event. It's shown in the code above:

```
$event->getEditLink()->href;
```

This will be available on a saved event. e.g.

```
$newEvent = $service->insertEvent($event);
echo $newEvent->getEditLink()->href;
```

Comment: hobodave - I looked at that, but what is confusing me is the "supplying the edit URL of the even" part. Let's say I just added an event, and now I want to delete it. How do I know what that event URL is? I added an edit to my original post with how I am adding an event, in case it helps any. Thanks for your help on this.

Comment: This was in my initial answer. I updated to make it clearer. Please *try* the code shown.

Comment: hobodave-

When I do the following:

echo $event->getEditLink()->href;

(Which is done right after an insert), nothing is echo'd. There output is just blank...

Any ideas? I don't know why this has been so hard for me!

Comment: I figured it out, I was missing: "$newEvent->when = array($when);"

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at [`Zend_Gdata`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html) and [`Zend_Gdata_Calendar`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.gdata.html) : those would probably help for all the hard work -- and if you don't have to spend code to communicate with Google's API, it gives you more time to develop other things ;-)

And it seems it can be used outsid of the Zend FRamework : it's even available as a standalone download : http://framework.zend.com/download/gdata

(If you really want to do it yourself, you can still try to understand how `Zend_Gdata` does it ^^ )

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that I have been using the Zend Framework to achieve what I have so far. But, even looking into the API, I can't seem to find out how to get an event url for a particular event!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GREAT resource to help you with this:
[Integrate your PHP application with Google Calendar](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-googleclndr/#ibm-pcon)

Here's how I obtain the unique ID of the calendar event after publishing the event with newEventEntry. I store the $id value in the database, in case I have to edit it later with update or delete.

```
    try {
        $event = $gcal->newEventEntry();        
        $event->title = $gcal->newTitle($title);        
        $when = $gcal->newWhen();
        $when->startTime = $start;
        $when->endTime = $end;
        $event->when = array($when);        
        $gcal->insertEvent($event);   
        $id = substr($event->id, strrpos($event->id, '/')+1); // trim off everything but the id 
      } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getResponse();
      }

 // Do mysql Insert functions here to store the record in db (removed for clarity)

      echo 'Event '. $id. 'successfully added!';
```

Then, when I need to access that particular event I can use it to target *just* that event for updating/deleting using a $_POST of the ID:

```
try {

 $event = $gcal->getCalendarEventEntry('http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/' . $_POST['id']);
        $event->title = $gcal->newTitle($title);
        $when = $gcal->newWhen();
        $when->startTime = $start;
        $when->endTime = $end;
        $event->when = array($when);
        $event->save();

    } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_Exception $e) {
        die("Error: " . $e->getResponse());
    } 
    echo 'Event successfully modified!';
```

Hope this answers your question - I struggled with getting this working, but share my findings with you here, if it helps I'm happy to have assisted.

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Well if you dont want to store event ids in local database, here another good way to deleting event if you have infomration about start time, end time and calendar id(specific calendar for which you want to delete event between start time and end time)

```
function deleteEvent($client,$startDate,$endDate,$startTime,$endTime,$tzOffset,$cal_id)
{
$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
$query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();
$query->setUser($cal_id);
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setProjection('full');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setStartMin("{$startDate}T{$startTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}");
$query->setStartMax("{$endDate}T{$endTime}:00.000{$tzOffset}");
$eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
   foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {
       $event->delete();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps to somebody, like it did to me.